# PHP source code encryption/Obfuscator

Tags: php, obfuscation

How can I encode or encrypt a PHP source code?

1. I've tried this one [PHP Base64 encoder](https://www.php-einfach.de/diverses/php-code-verschluesselung-php-obfuscator/), the problem is that it is easy to decrypt for someone who knows it.
2. For a stronger encryption I use this one [AES Enryption](http://aesencryption.net/), but if I encrypt some PHP code my page doesn't work.

Which is the best method? I don't want to use Ioncube or Loaders.

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should be more worried about someone being able to get to the source code at all...

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting PHP code may give you a false sense of security.  Truly encrypted code will not be able to run because the PHP parser won't make sense of it. I think it's more accurate to think of what you're trying to do as *scrambling* or *obfuscating* code. This makes the code much harder to read, but it's always reversible meaning that if you're protecting something of high value against a motivated adversary, the obfuscation will only buy you some time.

There are probably many solutions for obfuscating code. One of the more popular options is [IonCube Loader](http://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php). I've never used it and I'm not familiar with its effectiveness but it's the only one I know of. Others are welcome to add their feedback.

To protect your source files, you just don't want to put them in an environment where they can be accessed by someone you don't trust. For instance, a simple step you can take is to make sure that your crucial PHP files are outside of the publicly accessible directory on your webserver (typically called `public_html` or `www`).

Comment: "Truly encrypted code will not be able to run because the PHP parser won't make sense of it." - this is why solutions such as ionCube have an extension to execute the code. Encoding first compiles to bytecode, then adds protection to that. Some also encrypt, such as V9 ionCube where you can use Dynamic Keys that are not stored anywhere, solving the inherent weakness of stored keys. The OP doesn't want an extension though, so the only option is protecting source for pushing through eval(). This may be sufficient, but source can be exposed quite easily. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.

Comment: @Nick what do you mean by "*protecting source for pushing through eval()*"?

Comment: As you correctly say, PHP itself can only understand source, so any protector not using an extension has to restore mangled code to some form of source code. (AGH! Hate that accidentally hitting return posts a comment) The approach is then to call eval() on the restored source. Source can be exposed by patching the PHP engine API C routine that eval() uses.